# PHP Post Android Post

Tags: java, php, android, database, post

I want to make a post from my android application and insert into my database. My first approach was to send a post from my application and just show the value but it did not work.

My code from the application is

```
public void postData() {
    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", "sID"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("etc", "sETC"));

    try {

        String SetServerString = "";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://your-url.com/script.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        SetServerString = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

    }  catch(Exception ex) {
        // failed
    }
}
```

The php code is

```
<?php       
 include 'db.inc.php';
 $device_token  = urldecode($_POST['regid']);
 echo $device_token;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your lines

```
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
SetServerString = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

By

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

You can check response in android side using

```
String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(responseStr);
```

Use following PHP code to get values.

```
<?php       
$value1  = $_POST["regid"];
$value2 = $_POST["etc"];
echo $value1;
?>
```

Comment: Sadly it did not changed anything, could it be that my php code is wrong? I am really inexperienced with anything related to web programming.

Comment: Again it shows nothing but now I know it is not the php part but rather the android part that is not working.

Comment: try to print response in app side using above code.I think it will work .

Comment: I used Log instead of System.out.println(), and this is the result D/postdata: sID, it does work like you thought but I do not understand why it wont parse the data to the website.... or rather why post does not work...

Comment: sadly it does not, the php is fine, but I think the post is wrong since it does not POST the response to the website/php.

Comment: This code works only for android below 5.0. What do you mean by parse the data to website? If you get the request values on php side and response on android side , you can do whatever you wish to do.

Comment: I POST from my android application to the "website" (through the link "http://your-url.com/script.php") and want to show the posted data in my php file hence the website

Comment: So, you can use database to store data and retrieve it back to the website. Or for the test simply response back using echo and check whether your same value is sent back or not to android side. If you have got the same value as a http response, you are done . Other depends upon your business logic.